# TextFormField Enable/Disable According to Radio Button checked Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

How can i Enable/Disable `TextFormField` According to radio button when checked in flutter ?

```
      new Text('Allpages? :', style: new TextStyle(height: 1.0, fontSize: 15.2, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,)),
      new Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          new Radio(
            value: 0,
            groupValue: _printAllValue,
            onChanged: _setPrintAllValue,
          ),
          new Text('Yes'),
          new Radio(
            value: 1,
            groupValue: _printAllValue,
            onChanged: _setPrintAllValue,
          ),
          new Text('No'),
        ],
      ),
      new Padding(padding: new EdgeInsets.all(5.0)),
      new Text('Start and End pages :', style: new TextStyle(height: 1.0, fontSize: 15.2, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,)),
      new Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
            new Container(
           width: 200,
           child: new TextFormField(
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black87),
             textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
              keyboardType: TextInputType.phone,
             decoration: InputDecoration(
               labelText: 'Start Page',
              ),
           ),

         ),
          new Container(
            width: 200,
            child: new TextFormField(
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black87),
              textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
              keyboardType: TextInputType.phone,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                  labelText: 'End Page',
              ),
            ),

          ),
        ],
      ),

      new Padding(padding: new EdgeInsets.all(10.0)),
```

I need to  'Start Page', 'End Page' to be **activated** when check the `No` radio Button and **deactivated** when `yes` radio button checked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wrap your `TextFormField` inside `AbsorbPointer` and handle `absorb` property like:

```
bool _disable = false; // set this to false initially

AbsorbPointer(
  absorbing: _disable, // true makes TextFormField disabled and vice-versa
  child: TextFormField(),
)
```

Whenever you want to disable above field, you can change its property and actually fetch the value from your `Radio` and assign it to `_disable`

Edit:

There is a property in TextFormField, you can change that

```
TextFormField(
  enabled: !_disable, // set to false to disable it.
),
```

Comment: and how to disable it when radio is checked?

Comment: i made it like the way you mentioned , but when i am editing some of these TextFormField and checked radio while editing  it doesnt loose focus on this TextFormField  how to solve this point ?

Comment: how to clear text if there is any text found before disabling?

Comment: How many questions do you have dude, it's the third one now, just saying :) to clear text you can use `TextEditingController` and use `_controller.clear()`;

Comment: to be honest i found the controller solution before you answered me
all thanks to you man i will give you the accept !

Comment: No worries, glad I could help. Thanks again!